# Written data not visible in the file after writing with Gfortran and waiting using SLEEP()

Tags: fortran, sleep, gfortran, intel-fortran

I was making some tests with the code bellow when I faced an strange behavior in my program. When I use the call for the intrinsic subroutine "sleep" in my program nothing was written to the file testing.dat. If I removed the call for this subroutine it worked fine, the numbers were written. I tried the same code (calling the subroutine "sleep") with Intel Fortran and it worked fine as well.

It seems to me that the sleep subroutine halts in some sense the execution before the file is written with the program compiled using gfortran, behavior that does not occur using intel fortran. I'm not an computer science expert but that is my guess, does anyone else have a better one?
I tried with all the flags bellow and nothing has changed:

gfortran -g file.f90 -o executable

gfortran file.f90 -o executable

gfortran -O3 file.f90 -o executable

I am using a xubuntu 18.01 OS.

```
  program test
            implicit none
            integer ::       i, j, k
            open(34, file="testing.dat")
            do i=1,9999999
              do j=1,9999999
                do k=1,9999999
                    print*, i, j, k
                    write(34,'(3I8)') i, j, k
                    call sleep (1)
                end do
              end do
            end do
    end program
```

Comment: You do not close the file anywhere. Use `close(34)`. Do you actually plan to wait for 999999700000029999999 seconds? That will be a *very* long wait. Be aware that data could only be visible in the file after some buffering. Try smaller amount of data first, 9x9x9 should be enough. You can also try `flush(34)`.

Comment: You say the code compiles and works fine with Intel.  There are roughly 31536000 seconds in a year.  So, if the program does sleep, it will take 3.17e13 years to complete.  What does "works fine" mean?

Comment: Regarding the time to run the program I was just making some experiments using gdb (I am learning it). I was not expecting it to run all this time.

By working fine with intel fortran I mean that it wrote numbers to the file before the program finishes (I stopped it with Ctrl + c), while it does not happen with gfortran.

I reduced the amount of data to 2x2x2 and it wrote the numbers even with gfortran.

The final outcome for me is that if I'm using gdb to debug any program that combines sleep and write commands I can get empty files before the end of the execution.

Comment: Using flush(34) the program compiled with gfortran wrote to the file during execution as I was expecting. I did not know this function. Thank you @VladimirF

Comment: gfortran will buffer its output.  You can control this with environmental variables, which are documented in the manual.  See GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File output can be buffered. That means that the characters or bytes that are to be written in the external file are first gathered somewhere in memory and than written to the external file in larger chunks. That can speed-up file output. If you look at the external file i a random moment, it does not have to contain the output from all `write` statements that were executed, some may be in the buffers. The `flush(unit)` statement makes the data visible to the external processes by flushing the data. The gfortran manual for the older [`flush` intrinsic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLUSH.html) subroutine states

> The FLUSH intrinsic and the Fortran 2003 FLUSH statement have
> identical effect: they flush the runtime library's I/O buffer so that
> the data becomes visible to other processes. This does not guarantee
> that the data is committed to disk.

File buffering can also be typically controlled by compiler or runtime-library settings using compiler flags or environment variables. For gfortran you can find the runtime variables at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Runtime.html#Runtime

There are four variables you might be interested in:

`GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL`:        Do not buffer I/O for all units
`GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_PRECONNECTED`:       Do not buffer I/O for preconnected units.
`GFORTRAN_FORMATTED_BUFFER_SIZE`:     Buffer size for formatted files
`GFORTRAN_UNFORMATTED_BUFFER_SIZE`:       Buffer size for unformatted files

Comment: Note that even after flushing the data may be in other buffers or caches controlled by the OS or by the disk firmware and therefore "This does not guarantee that the data is committed to disk.".